# Firebase RealtimeDatabase retrieve snapshot object exception

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

This is my model class

```
    @Parcel
data class ClientModel(
    var name: String? = "",
    var phone: String? = "",
    var princpalAddresse: String? = "",
    var homeAddresse: String? = "",
    var travailleAddresse: String? = "",
    var email: String? = "",
    var userToken: String? = "",
    var principalAddresseCoords: Pair<Double, Double>? = null,
    var homeAddresseCoords: Pair<Double, Double>?= null,
    var workAddresseCoords: Pair<Double, Double>? = null,
)
```

My proGuard file keep the class :

```
 -keep class com.olivier.oplivre.models.ClientModel
```

But! when I try to get the snapshot with a *singleValueEventListener* I got exception because of the Pair<Double,Double> variables

```
   val utilisationInfo =  snapshot.getValue(ClientModel::class.java) //todo CRASH
```

Exception :

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class kotlin.Pair does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.
```

Database Structure :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sami Shorman said , firebase took my Pair instance and transform it but not as list, as Hashmap<*,*> ! so I changed my class model like that :

```
var principalAddresseCoords: HashMap<String,Double>? = null,
var homeAddresseCoords: HashMap<String,Double >? = null,
var workAddresseCoords: HashMap<String,Double >? = null,
```

To put the data as Hashmap I just had to do :

```
clientModel.workAddresseCoords =  HashMap<String,Double>().apply {
                    put("lat",lat)
                    put("long",long)
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think firebase Realtime database treat your **principalAddresseCoords** as a list of **long** so in your **ClientModel** change the value of **principalAddresseCoords** to emptyList() and the type **List**